# How to manually output publishing content from a variable

Tags: matlab, latex, publishing

When using the Publish feature of MATLAB, it typically publishes only what comes after the % signs or the function output. However, is there any command to take a variable and *splice its value into text*, possibly even creating LaTeX formulae from a MATLAB variable that holds a character string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### To use variables from the workspace

when Publishing to html using `disp()` with a html encoded string will add the lines to the output (without using the formatting for code output).

for example

```
str = sprintf('some value: %f from the workspace',variable)
disp(['<html>',str,'</html>'])
```

Notes:

- It is quite sensitive and you may need to add invisible section breaks between
  code output and lines produced in this way.
- Adding paragraph tags is useful to improve formatting
- Sadly (*to my knowledge*) the publishing markdown interpreter is not used on these lines, they are "*injected*" into the output, therefore **latex equations will not work**.

### Code

```
%% HTML option 
% This option is anly available with HTML output...
a=1;
str = ['The current value of a is ', num2str(a)];

%%%
% 
% When publishing to HTML using the |disp| function with HTML tags 
% surrounding the string can allow workspace variables to appear within 
% text.
% 
% For example the following line is created by evaluating code, it is not a
% comment in the m-file
% 
disp(['<html><p>',str,'</p></html>']);

%% Changing the value
% Now if we change a to 2...
a=2,str = ['The new value of a is ', num2str(a)];
%%
% Re-runing a similar code should show the updated value
disp(['<html><p>',str,'</p></html>'])
```

### Output

The code above generates the following:

> [image]

Comment: Works great for content, but I can't seem to be able to use LaTeX.

Comment: Sorry may have not give it enough attention or the right working but the 3rd bullet point was *inteded* to cover this... basically as far as I can tell text produced this way isn't interpreted by publish but is just "injected" into the html document

Answer (score 8):

Here is an example of rendering LaTeX formulae (one hard-coded in comments, other stored as a string in a variable).

```
%% LaTeX Examples
% Below are some equations rendered in LaTeX.
% (try to publish this file).
%

%% The definition of e
% Here we use equation embedded in the file.
%
% $$ e = \sum_{k=0}^\infty {1 \over {k!} } $$
%

%% The Laplace transform
% Here we render an equation stored in a variable.
%

% offscreen figure
fig = figure('Menubar','none', 'Color','white', ...
    'Units','inches', 'Position',[100 100 6 1.5]);
axis off

str = 'L\{f(t)\} \equiv  F(s) = \int_0^\infty\!\!{e^{-st}f(t)dt}';
text(0.5, 0.5, ['$$' str '$$'], 'Interpreter','latex', 'FontSize',28, ...
    'HorizontalAlignment','center', 'VerticalAlignment','middle')
snapnow
close(fig);
```

Here is how it looks like when the file is published as HTML:

[image: published_html]

You could wrap that last code in a helper function `render_latex_string(str)` and call it from different places.